# Como passar um valor string para um tipo no Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No meu mapeamento do entity, os campos que são FK ficaram assim:

```
public virtual T_Acao T_Acao { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<T_OsParceiro> T_OsParceiro { get; set; }
public virtual T_ProximaAcao T_ProximaAcao { get; set; }
```

No meu programa preciso passar um valor string, para o T_Acao. Como eu faço isso? Tentei um cast assim, mas não consegui:

```
tarefa.T_Acao = osParceiro.AcaoParceiro;
```

`AcaoParceiro` é do tipo `string`. Tentei um cast dessa forma:

```
tarefa.T_Acao = (SuporteTecnico.Models.T_Acao)osParceiro.AcaoParceiro;
```

O erro é:

> Cannot implicity convert type "string" to
>   `SuporteTecnico.Models.T_Acao`

Comment: O erro é claro. Você está tentando usar uma `string` pra atribuir a um objeto. Não entendi porque você precisa necessariamente passar uma `string`.

Comment: é que vem assim

Comment: Então coloque pra mim na pergunta todos os modelos, por favor: `T_Acao`, `T_OsParceiro`, `T_ProximaAcao`.

Answer (score 2):

Matei com a juda de um colega. Fiz assim:

```
T_Acao t = new T_Acao();
t.acao = osParceiro.Acao;
tarefa.T_Acao = t;
```